# Post large amount of data into a website using Python 2.7

Tags: python, urllib2, filehandle

I'm new to Python and I'm currently working on solving problems to improve my coding skills. There is a webpage where I need to post data like Name, Language (this a  drop down list), Phone number and Feedback. My idea here is to automate this process using a python script.  Please find the code and details below:

```
import urllib2
import requests
url = "http://example.com/feedback_details"

try:
    with open('review.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        data1=myfile.read()
    payload = {'Name:': '200272YV', 
               'Language:': 'Python 2.7', 
               'Phone Number:': '123456789', 
               'Feedback (not more than 200 characters):' = 'data1'
              }
    requests.post(url, data=payload)

except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
    print err.fp.read()
    print "Page Not Found"
```

I have written a feedback in a text document called `review.txt`and I have read the whole contents in that file to a variable called `data1`. So now I want to give this variable name in the  `'Feedback (not more than 200 characters):' =` as data so that the whole content in the file can be related to this. But I'm not able to assign as variable. How can I send the complete contents in the text file and assign it to the payload. Also, how can i check if this posting is done successfully or not. Can someone tell me where am I doing wrong. Is my approach wrong or flow is wrong. Thanks in advance. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *But I'm not able to assign as variable* - Why can't you assign it as a variable?

Comment: when I try to assign `'Feedback (not more than 200 characters):' = data1`, it throws an invalid syntax error

Comment: I'm not sure if i can assign it this way : `'Feedback (not more than 200 characters):' = 'data1'` as it will take the answer as data1 and not the contents of the file.

Comment: It *is* invalid syntax. You have an equality sign instead of a colon.

Comment: @kichik colon ? where ?

Comment: `'Feedback (not more than 200 characters)': = data1`

Comment: You accidentally put the colon inside the quoted string.

Comment: that colon is a part of the statement in the website. `'Feedback (not more than 200 characters):'` and then there is a box where i can enter the text and which is what i want to automate

Comment: It should be `'Feedback (not more than 200 characters):' : data1`, You use a colon for dictionaries, not equal signs

Comment: thanks all. Understood my mistake and i have corrected it. How do i know if the request has been submitted ? there is submit button that i haven't clicked yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
import urllib2
import requests
url = "http://example.com/feedback_details"

try:
    with open('review.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        data1=myfile.read()
    payload = {'Name:': '200272YV', 
               'Language:': 'Python 2.7', 
               'Phone Number:': '123456789', 
               'Feedback (not more than 200 characters)': data1
              }
    requests.post(url, data=payload)

except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
    print err.fp.read()
    print "Page Not Found"
```

Comment: Thank you. got to know my mistake. there is a submit button that i havent clicked , but will `requests.post(url, data=payload)` help in submitting the data and going to the next page ?